# Sorting keys in an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I need to sort the keys in an RDD, but there is no natural sorting order (not ascending or descending). I wouldn't even know how to write a Comparator to do it. Say I had a map of apples, pears, oranges, and grapes, I want to sort by oranges, apples, grapes, and pears.

Any ideas on how to do this in Spark/Scala? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, you need to look for the `Ordering[T]` trait rather than the `Comparator` interface -- mostly a cosmetic difference so that the focus is on the attribute of the data rather than a thing which compares two instances of the data.  Implementing the trait requires that the `compare(T,T)` method be defined.  A very explicit version of the enumerated comparison could be:

```
object fruitOrdering extends Ordering[String] {
  def compare(lhs: String, rhs: String): Int = (lhs, rhs) match {
    case ("orange", "orange") => 0
    case ("orange", _)        => -1
    case ("apple", "orange")  => 1
    case ("apple", "apple")   => 0
    case ("apple", _)         => -1
    case ("grape", "orange")  => 1
    case ("grape", "apple")   => 1
    case ("grape", "grape")   => 0
    case ("grape", _)         => -1
    case ("pear", "orange")   => 1
    case ("pear", "apple")    => 1
    case ("pear", "grape")    => 1
    case ("pear", "pear")     => 0
    case ("pear", _)          => -1
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

Or, to slightly adapt [zero323's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277219/2636793):

```
object fruitOrdering2 extends Ordering[String] {
  private val values = Seq("orange", "apple", "grape", "pear")
  // generate the map based off of indices so we don't have to worry about human error during updates
  private val ordinalMap = values.zipWithIndex.toMap.withDefaultValue(Int.MaxValue)

  def compare(lhs: String, rhs: String): Int = ordinalMap(lhs).compare(ordinalMap(rhs))
}
```

Now that you have an instance of `Ordering[String]`, you need to inform the `sortBy` method use this ordering rather than the built-in one.  If you look at the signature for `RDD#sortBy` you'll see the full signature is

```
def sortBy[K](f: (T) ⇒ K, ascending: Boolean = true, numPartitions: Int = this.partitions.length)(implicit ord: Ordering[K], ctag: ClassTag[K]): RDD[T]
```

That implicit `Ordering[K]` in the second parameter list is normally looked up by the compiler for pre-defined orderings -- that's how it knows what the natural ordering should be.  Any implicit parameter, however, can be given an explicit value instead.  Note that if you supply one implicit value then you need to supply all, so in this case we also need to provide the `ClassTag[K]`.  That's always generated by the compiler but can be easily explicitly generated using `scala.reflect.classTag`.

Specifying all of that, the invocation would look like:

```
import scala.reflect.classTag
rdd.sortBy { case (key, _) => key }(fruitOrdering, classOf[String])
```

---

That's still pretty messy, though, isn't it?  Luckily we can use implicit classes to take away a lot of the cruft.  Here's a snippet that I use fairly commonly:

```
package com.example.spark

import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

package object implicits {
  implicit class RichSortingRDD[A : ClassTag](underlying: RDD[A]) {
    def sorted(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): RDD[A] =
      underlying.sortBy(identity)(ord, implicitly[ClassTag[A]])

    def sortWith(fn: (A, A) => Int): RDD[A] = {
      val ord = new Ordering[A] { def compare(lhs: A, rhs: A): Int = fn(lhs, rhs) }
      sorted(ord)
    }
  }

  implicit class RichSortingPairRDD[K : ClassTag, V](underlying: RDD[(K, V)]) {
    def sortByKey(implicit ord: Ordering[K]): RDD[(K, V)] = 
      underlying.sortBy { case (key, _) => key } (ord, implicitly[ClassTag[K]])

    def sortByKeyWith(fn: (K, K) => Int): RDD[(K, V)] = {
      val ord = new Ordering[K] { def compare(lhs: K, rhs: K): Int = fn(lhs, rhs) }
      sortByKey(ord)
    }
  }
}
```

And in action:

```
import com.example.spark.implicits._

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("grape", 0.3), ("apple", 5.0), ("orange", 5.6)))
rdd.sortByKey(fruitOrdering).collect
// Array[(String, Double)] = Array((orange,5.6), (apple,5.0), (grape,0.3))

rdd.sortByKey.collect // Natural ordering by default
// Array[(String, Double)] = Array((apple,5.0), (grape,0.3), (orange,5.6))

rdd.sortWith(_._2 compare _._2).collect  // sort by the value instead
// Array[(String, Double)] = Array((grape,0.3), (apple,5.0), (orange,5.6))
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a `sortBy` method in Spark which allows you to define an arbitrary ordering and whether you want ascending or descending. E.g.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq ( ("a", 1), ("z", 7), ("p", 3), ("a", 13)  ))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[331] at parallelize at <console>:70

scala> rdd.sortBy( _._2, ascending = false) .collect.mkString("\n")
res34: String = 
(a,13)
(z,7)
(p,3)
(a,1)

scala> rdd.sortBy( _._1, ascending = false) .collect.mkString("\n")
res35: String = 
(z,7)
(p,3)
(a,1)
(a,13)

scala> rdd.sortBy

def sortBy[K](f: T => K, ascending: Boolean, numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[K], ctag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K]): RDD[T]
```

The last part tells you what the signature of `sortBy` is. The ordering used in previous examples is by the first and second part of the pair.

**Edit**: answered too quickly, without checking your question, sorry... Anyway, you would define your ordering like in your example:

```
def myord(fruit:String) = fruit match {
    case "oranges" => 1 ; 
    case "apples" => 2; 
    case "grapes" =>3;  
    case "pears" => 4; 
    case _ => 5}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("apples", "oranges" ,  "pears", "grapes" , "other") )
```

Then, the result of ordering would be:

```
scala> rdd.sortBy[Int](myord, ascending = true).collect.mkString("\n")
res1: String = 
oranges
apples
grapes
pears
other
```

Comment: This looks very close to what I want. But rather than a Seq, I have a Map of fruits ("apples" -> "good", "oranges" -> "better", "pears" -> "great"). So how would I then sort k of the k, v?

Answer (score 2):

If the only way you can describe the order is enumeration then simply enumerate:

```
val order = Map("orange" -> 0L, "apple" -> 1L, "grape" -> 2L, "pear" -> 3L)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("grape", 0.3), ("apple", 5.0), ("orange", 5.6)))
val sorted = rdd.sortBy{case (key, _) => order.getOrElse(key, Long.MaxValue)}
sorted.collect

// Array[(String, Double)] = Array((orange,5.6), (apple,5.0), (grape,0.3))
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like that! But I'm working with key -> value pairs already. Where would I add the enumerator?

Comment: If it will be reused you should consider creating  a broadcast variable otherwise code like provided above should work just fine. Any variable referenced inside closures is automatically serialized and transfered to all workers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about spark, but with pure Scala collections that would be

```
_.sortBy(_.fruitType)
```

For example,

```
val l: List[String] = List("the", "big", "bang")
val sortedByFirstLetter = l.sortBy(_.head)
// List(big, bang, the)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I don't quite understand. How does that allow me to specify which piece of fruit I want to come first, and so on?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally wrote `groupBy` instead of `sortBy`. Updated the answer.